# Multiple Interface implementaion property mapping - NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

Hi everyone I'm faced with the following issue, to which i'm sure there must be a solution but i cannot seems to find one.

Looking at the following small piece of code (assuming ID's and all exists):

```
interface IBehave
{}

class A : IBehave
{}

class B : IBehave
{}

class Owner
{
    IBehave Behave { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what i'm looking to accomplish:
Assuming A and B are already mapped by their concrete classes
I want to map the Owner class in such a way that querying it will
instantiate the correct interface implementation as the property.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you checked out http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete and the entry right below that one?

Comment: Yes I have, they seem to be referring to subclasses as in inherited subclasses unless i missed the point.

Comment: That documentation is outlining exactly the situation you are in.